# How can I have timestamp displayed in UTC+02 (same timezone) for both the queries below?

Tags: postgresql, timezone

My first query is:

```
SELECT distinct wfc_request_job_id,wfc_request_job_info,
               replace(iso_cc,';',' ') as "iso_cc",to_char(wfc_request_start_ts,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as ts,
               sent_message_count,
               (link_object_count + poi_object_count + point_address_object_count) as request_object_count 
FROM wfc_request_job 
where 
wfc_request_job_id=173526;
```

This returns ts as 2015-08-16 03:08:59

Second Query:

```
SELECT wfc_request_job_id,wfc_request_start_ts,wfc_request_end_ts,replace(iso_cc,';',' ') as "iso_ccs",sent_message_count,wfc_queue_name 
FROM wfc_request_job
where 
to_char(wfc_request_start_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD') >= to_char(to_date('08/16/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD') 
and to_char(wfc_request_start_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD') <= to_char(to_date('08/16/2015','MM/DD/YYYY'),'YYYY-MM-DD')
order by wfc_request_job_id desc
```

This returns ts of the job id mentioned above as - "2015-08-16 15:58:59.809+02"

How can I make both the queries return ts in UTC+02 - i.e. same timezone

The data type of `wfc_request_start_ts` is - timestamp with timezone

I changed to queries to have the format HH24:MI:SS however that did not help. Please note that the webapp using these queries will be opened in both Germany and USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to postgresql manual [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) there is TZ (and OF as of v9.4) template patterns for Date/Time formatting.

Therefore in query you need to add it so

```
postgres=# select to_char(now(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:ss TZ');
        to_char         
------------------------
 2015-08-19 12:08:56 CEST
(1 row)
```

Also, make sure you specify timezone when converting
so instead

```
to_date('08/16/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

use

```
TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2015-08-16 00:00:00+02';
```

in second query.